# Find Value in another sheet, Copy offset (old sheet), paste offset (New Sheet)

Tags: excel, vba

I wonder if you can help me build a VBA script that does the following:

Searched for a value taken from column C in sheet1, and finds it in column C sheet2, copy value in column B sheet1 (offset) and pastes it to the same row it found the value C to column B (offset)

Keep in mind that the data are ordered the same row on both sides, therefor i need Find function.

It needs to go in loop untill last row is done in sheet1 (searched all rows and copied value from sheet1, and paste value to sheet2)

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You don't need a code for this, you could achieve that with the functions MATCH and INDIRECT.

Comment: Problem is that these cointain 750k of line so this will take forever or?

Comment: @Damian, did you mean MATCH and **INDEX** ?

Comment: Correct, didnt think about it as a solution, but that would work i guess can you help me make it, it needs to loop thro all rows in sheet 1 tho

Comment: mmmm my excel is in spanish, so it's a bit challenging keep it up with the english versions. I tried on my excel and i used MATCH, INDIRECT and ADDRESS. If vlookup would work with negative columns it'd be easier but...

Comment: Thought I don't really get what are you asking for @JonasKorani Could you explain it with a sample of your sheet? I don't know if you want the value on the sheet1 or the sheet2

Comment: @Damian - Check [this site](https://www.excel-function-translation.com/index.php?page=english-spanish.html) out, if you want help translating Excel formulas

Comment: I uploaded pictures if you can check it out

Answer (score 0):

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dScdY.jpg)

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jxFr.jpg)

As you can see Sheet1 contains some comments, while sheet2 does not, also sheet2 have more rows with some different values.

I want to be able to make the program locate the Item1 Column in Sheet2 and add to it the comments from sheet1, to sheet2 comments

Answer (score 0):

With this formula on column b from sheet2 should work

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(C2;Sheet1!$C:$C);2;1;1;"Sheet1"))
```

Comment: I have 50k rows of text in my document, It will be way to slow using formula, therefor i thought VBA code would help much more

Comment: Start recording, insert the formula, autofill it down and copy paste values. Stop recording. There goes your code.

Comment: This formula is not working for me, Because the comment are just putting itself in the first column not following the tagname (Itemname) So when i download and update sheet2 to newest version, those comments are just from the old but not putting themself at the right row depandent on the value of item column

Also it is making my workbook way to slow

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank you for the contribution, i managed to make it work finally.
I found this script (sry dont remember who owns it, and modified it to my needs)

```
Sub test()


Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim oCell As Range


Dim i As Long
i = 2

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data New")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mellomlagring")

Do While ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    Set oCell = ws2.Range("H:H").Find(What:=ws1.Cells(i, 8))
    If Not oCell Is Nothing Then ws1.Cells(i, 2) = oCell.Offset(0, -6)
    i = i + 1
Loop

Set ws1 = Nothing
Set ws2 = Nothing
End Sub
```